# Spring: How to inject a property value into the bean via XML?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I have a bean with injected field value. It works just fine. I use annotation to ask `Spring` to inject value from `properties` into the bean.

```
public class MyBean {
    @Value("${app.settings.value}")
    private String value;
}
```

How can I do the same via XML? I've tried to inject using `value="#{}"`.

```
<bean id="myBean" class="com.test.MyBean">
    <property name="value" value="{app.settings.value}"/>
</bean>
```

But my approach does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<bean id="myBean" class="com.test.MyBean">
    <property name="value" value="${app.settings.value}"/>
</bean>
```

The syntax is the same as for java config - prefixed with the `$` sign.