# Spring batch xml repositoryitemwriter schema placeholder form properties

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-batch

Need to get the schema name from properties file for spring batch application.
Where the schema name is different for dev and prod for MSSQL database.

Job configuration in xml as below

```
<bean id="dataItemWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter">
    <property name="assertUpdates" value="true" />
    <property name="itemPreparedStatementSetter">
        <bean class="org.test.batch.model.ItemStatementMapper" />
    </property>
    <property name="sql" >
                <value>
                    <![CDATA[
                            INSERT INTO dbo.EMPLOYEE
                                   (PROJECT_NAME
                                   ,APP_NAME
                                   ,EMPLOYEE_NAME)
                                   values (?,?,?)
                    ]]>
                </value>
    </property>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataDataSource" />
</bean>
```

The schema name "dbo" should be retrieved form proprieties file so that DEV and PROD this can be changed in configuration

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring: How to inject a property value into the bean via XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34882646/spring-how-to-inject-a-property-value-into-the-bean-via-xml)

Comment: But here i have replacement in the query inside the CDATA.The place holder will not work

Comment: I don't see the need to put the value in a CDATA block, there are no special xml characters in your query. Here is an example: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/8762e3411557aaf887867f8d8594b01127538cb1/spring-batch-core/src/test/resources/org/springframework/batch/core/resource/ListPreparedStatementSetterTests-context.xml#L25. If this might happen, you can externalize the query in a properties file where the substitution should work.

Comment: yes this work by removing CDATA. thanks

Comment: Glad to hear that. I added an answer, please accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the need to put the value in a `CDATA` block, there are no special xml characters in your query. Here is an example: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/8762e3411557aaf887867f8d8594b01127538cb1/spring-batch-core/src/test/resources/org/springframework/batch/core/resource/ListPreparedStatementSetterTests-context.xml#L25. So in your case, it should be something like:

```
<bean id="dataItemWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter">
    <property name="assertUpdates" value="true" />
    <property name="itemPreparedStatementSetter">
        <bean class="org.test.batch.model.ItemStatementMapper" />
    </property>
    <property name="sql" >
        <value>
           INSERT INTO dbo.EMPLOYEE (PROJECT_NAME ,APP_NAME ,EMPLOYEE_NAME) values (?,?,?)
        </value>
    </property>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataDataSource" />
</bean>
```